# Get UTF-8 file from URL in Java

Tags: java, url, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to retrieve lyrics of a song from an URL. It works, expect accented characters that are not shown properly (get something like �). I think there is an encoding problem. But I do not know how to fix that.

Thanks for your help

```
StringBuilder lyric = new StringBuilder();

// Get lyric from API
URL url = new URL("http://api.ntag.fr/lyrics/?artist="
        + this.artist + "&title=" + this.title);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    lyric.append(str).append("\r\n");
}
in.close();
```

Comment: Check the value of the content type header in the response? That should have the actual character encoding in it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType()

Comment: @BrettOkken got "text/plain; charset=utf-8"

Comment: That seems to leave 2 possibilities. 1. It isn't actually utf-8. 2. The application/font being used to display the string does not have a glyph for the code point. What specific url (artist and title) are you requesting?

Comment: @BrettOkken the specific url is: http://api.ntag.fr/lyrics/?artist=rammstein&title=dalai%20lama And the font is ok, it works if I write accented char directly.

Comment: I also thought of checking the actual contents. http://api.ntag.fr/lyrics/?artist=stromae&title=formidable contains properly encoded UTF-8 characters. Can you download a file, immediately save it to a local file, and check if using this has the same problem?

Comment: @Jongware if I download the file, everyting works great.

Comment: Check the string values in a debugger.  If your debugger says the characters are fine, you need to look close at your output device.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the char does not work even in the debugger

Comment: Then the page does not use UTF-8 encoding.  Considered using a ready made library for this?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I would like, but I do not know any library for this.

Comment: What are you doing with the String after you have read it into the StringBuilder?

Comment: @BrettOkken I dislay it in a JLabel.

Comment: What are the actual byte values you are getting? Have you tried populating the Accept-Charset header in the request?

Comment: @BrettOkken yes without luck. But i have noticed that this bug only appear with this specific song and not with others. So, I do not think that is a big problem.